# c++ makefile project in eclipse - select() returns strangely fast in stdin

Tags: c++, eclipse, stdin

My Eclipse project is a C++ with makefile project. After at the end of the makefile, there is a call to the executable as if from terminal. (./myEXE)

This program is expected to accept commands from the terminal upon runtime (it is a physics simulation using MPI, with possibility to input "stop" or "stats" or "stop" commands while the simulation runs).

The input is written (not my original code) with a `select()` (from library sys/types, [this](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?select%202) for example) to see if there is anything readable from the stdin. The timeout option for select() makes sure MPI has time to start. After trying to read input for a while, it will check that the MPI workloads progress, and if they don't, it will raise timeout error.

Everything works like a charm when I call the makefile from terminal. It is broken when trying to run from Eclipse (shift+F9 and so on...)

It seems the problem is that stdin is always readable, thus checks on MPI before it has the possibility to initiate simulations - `select()` returns after <1ms.

My two main questions are therefore:

- Where is Eclipse reading stdin from?
- Why is it always readable?

P.S. Since the program is called via MPI in the makefile instead of directly from Eclipse, its a bit tricky to debug it all....

Comment: What does the code do when `stdin` is readable to make it no longer readable? If you don't do anything, it will remain readable forever.

Comment: `read(filedescriptor, buffer, buffersize)` which returns 0 (eof) in both the case of terminal and eclipse. maybe I dont really understand what `select()`does... :S

Comment: UPDATE: my bad. correct should be: (i) run from terminal means `select` and `read` works as they should. nothing is read unless i enter a line in my terminal. (ii) run from eclipse means `stdin`is readable and `read` returns 0 (eof) after 1 ms

Answer (score 1):

When `select` says `stdin` is readable, you must make sure to change its state before you call `select` again, otherwise it will just return immediately. Your code doesn't change its state but instead just calls `select` again, causing it to loop forever.

How you should fix it depends on whether `stdin` being closed is a fatal condition for your program. If your program must have a working `stdin` to continue, then if it gets an EOF while reading `stdin`, it should terminate, not just keep `select`ing blindly. If your program can continue to run usefully even without a working `stdin`, then it should take it out of its `select` set if it closes or errors. (Or stop calling `select`, depending on the logic.)

But you can't just ignore the case and keep running as if nothing happened.

Comment: Thnk you for clarifying. I thought `stdin` would change state when all its lines has been read. When `stdin` is connected to my good old bash terminal, it will change state as each line has been read and will not be readable until i press enter again (submit a new readable line). This seems to not be the case for the eclipse console, and is the reason why i ask. What is the default `stdin` for eclipse really?

Comment: Hi! Still, `select` returns that it is readable.... There is something fishy here, but eventually I worked around it instead of solving it. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @LudvigH Of course `select` returns that it is readable, it's readable. Stop calling `select` to get information you already have! (You can't wait for something to become readable if it can't become readable.)